# Как реализовать индикатор положения телефона?

Tags: java, android

Я подключил акселерометр который отслеживает положение телефона(угол наклона верхней части устройства от пользователя или к нему) и в зависимости от этого позволяет либо не позволяет делать те или иные действия.

Так вот вопрос в том, подскажите как можно визуально показать юзеру такую плавающую точку(индикатор положения) как на строительном уровне, когда наклоняешь телефон пузырек движется либо вверх либо вниз в зависимости от стороны наклона, что то вроде кастромного `seekbar`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может как то установить лисенер на `seekbar` и через сетер передавать ему значения с акселерометра таким образом ползунок должен будет двигаться...

Но мне кажется должны быть более правильные решения, во всяком случае на телефонах есть стандартная настройка "Настроить калибровку" и там реализовано это хорошо, но как?

Comment: Ну вот, получилось же.

Comment: @metalurgus  )) без вашего совета ничего не вышло бы))

Comment: @metalurgus сейчас к слову, вроде нашел как можно реализовать с помощью `linear gauge`...

Comment: Я думаю, что можно у `SeekBar` делать `setProgress()`, значения для которого брать у одной из осей аксилометра (не могу сообразить, у какой именно, голова болит). Только сначала нужно это значение обработать, и преобразовать в `int`. Можете словами (а лучше картинками) описать, в каком положении телефона *пузырек* должен быть в самом верху и самом низу?

Comment: @metalurgus По Z оси нужно, у меня уже есть значения и пределы от и до. Я вот думаю, что если реализовать через `SeekBar` то здесь несколько вопросов. Во первых нужно будет его кастомизировать чтоб нарисовать пределы и покрасить части в зеленый и красный, для меня это пока не просто... Во вторых вопрос можно ли отключить возможность чтоб юзер мог сам его двигать? Видь первоначальная задача `SeekBar` именно в этом... Я чуть позже отпишу может ли это все реализовать `linear gauge` мне кажется это и проще будет и красивее...

Comment: отключить проще простого - `enabled="false"`. Покрасить, как вам надо - уже сложнее. Но все это делается через стили.

Comment: @metalurgus а есть пример как через стили это можно сделать? Просто мне кажется что даже стилями не нарисуешь так, я думаю нужно наследовать и переопределять все как нужно...

Comment: @metalurgus вот в итоге я опубликовал ответ... Долго я копался с этой штукой)) Но зато много че понял, например как работать со стилями)) и кстати `enabled="false"` в отношении `SeekBar` не применима... Там немного по другому реализовано

Answer (score 12, accepted):

В итоге у меня получилось все это сделать и все отлично работает. Хотя я не понимаю, почему в доступе нет примеров я думаю что это не должно быть такой  редкостью.

Вот специально для тех кому может это пригодиться я собрал проект с реализацией и [выложил на `Git`](https://github.com/alekseytimoshchenko/Accelerometer-indicator) , я новичок, так что может вы найдете как это можно улучшить, но во всяком случае это работает. Сейчас индикатор показывает положение относительно оси Z , но там все подготовлено под оси X и Y . надеюсь кому то еще поможет и если что то можете подсказать как улучшить

Вот как это все сделано

**Main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
private VerticalSeekBar seekBar1;
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor sensorAccel;
private Sensor sensorLinAccel;
private Sensor sensorGravity;

private static float axisX;
private static float axisY;
private static float axisZ;

private Timer timer;

private static int seekBarFloatingPoint;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initVar();
    startTip();
}

private void initVar() {
    seekBar1 = (VerticalSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorAccel = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensorLinAccel = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
    sensorGravity = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);
}

private SensorEventListener listener = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            axisX = event.values[0];
            axisY = event.values[1];
            axisZ = event.values[2];
        }
    }

};

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(listener);
    timer.cancel();
}

private void startTip() {
    sensorManager.registerListener(listener, sensorAccel,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sensorManager.registerListener(listener, sensorLinAccel,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sensorManager.registerListener(listener, sensorGravity,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int convert = (int) (axisZ * 100);
                    int i = 500;
                    seekBarFloatingPoint = i + convert;
                    seekBar1.setProgress(seekBarFloatingPoint);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 200);
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if (fromUser) {
        seekBar1.setProgress(seekBarFloatingPoint);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}
}
```

Потом XML файлы со стилями в папке `drawable`

**progress**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/background_fill" />

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:drawable="@drawable/progress_fill" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

**background_fill**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners android:radius="5px" />
<stroke
    android:width="10dp"
    android:color="#00ffffff" />
</shape>
```

**progress_fill**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners android:radius="5px" />
<stroke
    android:width="10dp"
    android:color="#00ffffff" />
</shape>
```

**styleseekbarcamera**

```
<gradient
    android:startColor="#be0101"
    android:centerColor="#68be0101"
    android:endColor="#be0101"
    android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

**styleseekbarthumb**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#ffffff" />
<size
    android:width="10dp"
    android:height="30dp" />

<solid android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

**styleseekbardivider**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
android:thickness="0dp">
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#000000" />

<corners android:radius="0dp" />

<solid android:color="#268e00" />

</shape>
```

Вот только еще б хотелось, чтоб `thumb` плавно перемещался, он должен как бы плавать, а так получается, что он прыгает. Если кто то знает как это сделать подскажите

Comment: будет очень правильно, если вы изложите основные моменты (и код) решения прямо в ответе.

Comment: @pavlofff добавил

Answer (score 0):

Так а что Вам мешает:

1. Создать свой компонент
2. Принцип его работы просто - в контейнер, кладёте например картинку и задаёте ей позиционирование при приходе событий с акселерометра.
3. Пункт первый в принципе не обязателен, но для кошерного решения необходим.

Comment: Я новичок и не до конца понял, что вы имеете ввиду... Создать компонент понятно, положить в контейнер(в моем случае `linearLayout`) , а вот что значит задавать позеционирование?

Comment: Не уверен что подойдёт linearLayout, разве что картинке внутри выставлять маргины. Либо использовать relativeLayout например.